# Refund policy for left project

Tags: payment-terms, payments

There is some guy x. Who wants to make a game. He hired y. This y can't develop unity game. Just based on years of experience he was hired or something. Now y hired me. The project was split into many milestones.

1. (Upfront Payment) - USD 500
2. (Backend + Frontend) - USD 300

- User Management(Creation, Deletion, Management, etc.)
- Fund Transfer Between Users

3. (Web socket backend + implement) - USD 500

- Basic Server to Device Communication System Development

And there were more milestones. But for some personal reason, I had to leave the project. And I delivered all these three milestones and got payment after the source code delivery is complete.

After leaving the project, now he is asking for a complete refund. Can anyone, give me some suggestions, how to handle this?

Comment: What is the refund claim based on? Is there a contract with a refund clause?

Comment: @morsor No, there was no refund clause mentioned. And he cleared only payments of the milestones completed. And asking refund of those cleared milestones.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the contract dictates payment upon milestone completion regardless of whether the entire project is completed - and the client has paid in full, it seems they have no legal basis for a refund.

They may want the money back because their goals have changed - but that is not your problem.

Depending on your jurisdiction, they could make this your problem by taking you to court. Regardless of them having a bad case, this could be expensive for both parties and therefore will almost certainly not happen.

Comment: Agreed. They're trying their luck in the hopes that OP just gives them their money back. He should tell them that he'll see them in court and that'll be the last he ever hears from them. Any competent solicitor will tell them that milestone payments can't be claimed back *at the end of a contract*.